# Git pushes to wrong heroku app

Tags: git, heroku

This I'm sure is based solely on my lack of understanding of git, The problem is I don't know what I don't know.

I have a successful app deployed to Heroku. It tracks work orders for my fire dept. In my normal work flow, I use `$ git push heroku master` from the app directory to deploy my changes. I needed to set this same app up for another fire dept. So I figured I'd make a copy of it on my local machine, set up a new heroku app, make the changes needed to make the new copy specific to the new fire dept. I'd run `git init` etc, then push it up to the new heroku app. Problem is, it pushes up to the old one. 
I figure this is because all the git settings were copied when I copied the app directory. How do I make it separate, so they act like 2 unique apps?

Is there a certain feature/area of git that I should learn about to understand what's going on here?

Comment: To anyone else with git confusion: I watched the beginner Git course on lynda.com and now I'd never make a mistake like this because the whole system is crystal clear. (not a paid spokesperson, honest)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indeed, you should understand what is a remote repository.

You can for example type `git remote -v` and see the result to clearly see where you are pushing.

from there, `git remote rm heroku` allows you to remove the remote repository.
And `git remote add heroku {address}` allows you to add a remote repository whose address you should specify.

The address of the corresponding remote is provided by heroku. Go on the app details on the heroku website and copy paste it from there. After that, the git push heroku master should push to the good repository.

When you copy pasted, the project, you also copy pasted the .git directory of the project so all the old settings of git for it. I think that a `git clone` would have been a better approach

Comment: ahhhh... very good, thank-you. I haven't made many changes, would it be worth it to delete the directory, and do a `git clone`?

Comment: @bennett_an It does not change that much so it's fine, just understand how to manage your remote repository. I think I gave you the 3 commands that are useful in that case.
The above commands were git ones. But you can also manage it through the heroku command line tool.
If you type `heroku list`, you should see both your applications.
Remove the previous remote first.
To add a remote, you can either use the `git remote add {remoteAddress}` or the `heroku git:remote -app {appName}` I think

Comment: If you think my answer solved your problem, please tag it as the correct answer please :)